# (400) Bad Requestwhen using the permission to the library google-api-php-client

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

Uploading a file and immediately do permission->update:

```
public function  sharingFile() {
    $fileId = $this->file['id'];
    $permissionId = $this->file['userPermission']['id'];
    try {
        $permission = $this->service->permissions->get($fileId, $permissionId);
        $permission->setRole('writer');
        $permission->setType('default');
        print_r($permission);
        return $this->service->permissions->update($fileId, $permissionId, $permission);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return "Error: " . $e;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

and get an error:

```
Error: exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling PUT
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B6xE_F1PfpXTbF9IdHgxbEJueEk/permissions/me:
(400) Bad Request' in Z:\home\site.com\www\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php:66
Stack trace:
#0 Z:\home\site.com\www\google-api-php-client\src\io\Google_REST.php(36):  Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
#1 Z:\home\site.com\www\google-api-php-client\src\service\Google_ServiceResource.php(186): Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest))
#2 Z:\home\site.com\www\google-api-php-client\src\contrib\Google_DriveService.php(774): Google_ServiceResource->__call('update', Array)
```

it may be a bug in the library?
Help, please.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to update permissions for the document owner and make that user a writer instead. A Drive document must have exactly one owner, so your request is invalid.

Comment: Share and permission it's not the same thing? In this case do file sharing for all?

Comment: Made through the insert. Type set to "anyone" and the role to "reader"